# Using jquery load function to load a .DAE file inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to be able to click a button and load a .DAE file inside a div, then click another button and load another.DAE file inside the same div, replacing the contents. I've tried using the jquery load function in the code below but when i click the button, loads of words and numbers appear (relating to the .DAE file) instead of the actual model.

Any help is greately apperciated.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#LBC').click(function() {
    $('#target').load('blood.DAE');
});



});
</script>

<title>Visualising Cells</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="three.js"></script>
<script src="ColladaLoader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<script>

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;


var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.01, 500 );
camera.position.z = 0.16;
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
scene.add(camera);


var renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(width,height); 
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.render(scene,camera);
renderer.setClearColor("rgb(181,181,181)");

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
        scene.add(light);

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(0, 0, 0.14);
        scene.add(light);



var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    loader.load('blood.DAE', function (collada) {

            object = collada.scene;
            object.position.x = 0;
            object.position.y = 0;
            object.position.z = 0;
            object.updateMatrix();
            scene.add(object);
            }
            );



document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
console.log("Up Arrow Pressed");
console.log(camera.position.z);
if (event.keyCode == 38) {

    if (camera.position.z >= 0.1) {

        camera.position.z = camera.position.z - 0.01;

    }

}

else if (event.keyCode == 40) {

    console.log("Down Arrow Pressed")

    if (camera.position.z < 0.2) {

        camera.position.z = camera.position.z + 0.01;
    }

    }
}, true);

render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);

object.rotation.x += 0.01;
object.rotation.y += 0.01;

renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };
        render();


</script>

<div class="float-btn">
<input type="button" id="LBC">Load Red Blood Cell</input>
<input type="button" id="LEC">Load Egg Cell</input>
</div>

<div class="float-txt">
<div style="color:#000000">
<div style="font-family: Arial">
<div style="font-size: 18px">
<div style="text-decoration: underline">
<h1>Visualising Microscopic Cells</h1>
</div>

<div class="instructions">
<div style="color:#000000">
<div style="font-family: Arial">
<div style="font-size: 16px">
<div style="text-decoration: underline">
<h2>Instructions</h2>
</div>

<div class="instruction-txt">
<div style="color:#000000">
<div style="font-family: Arial">
<div style="font-size: 14px">
<p><u>Zoom In:</u> <strong>Up Arrow</strong> <br><u>Zoom Out:</u> <strong>Down Arrow</strong></br></p>
</div>

<div class="Model-Location" id="target">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

css

```
canvas {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.float-btn{
position: fixed;
bottom: 5px;
left: 5px;
}

.float-txt{
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 10px;
}

.instructions{
position: fixed;
bottom: 100px;
right: 28px;
}

.instruction-txt{
position: fixed;
right: 10px;
}

.Model-Location{
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
height: 500px;
width: 500px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You see a content of `DAE` file, as `load` function just fetch a file and append it content into a specific place. It will not render it like a model. You need at least to have a plugin to do it, and include in your page as an `object` or `embed` tag.

Comment: Sorry, im new to jquery and a bit confused with your answer, is it possible for you to correct my code?

Comment: Also, would it be less complicated to use jquery to toggle between the models on the page, in the code above one model is already on the page. In other words is it possible to use jquery to switch between the model displayed then assign that to each of the buttons?

Comment: that's the basics. Of course with `jQuery` it simple, but better to learn JavaScript, so you know how it's working.

Comment: I'm still confused with the answer you provided.

Comment: Is there any chance you can elaborate on your answer?